# Change superclass without modifying original code

Tags: python, oop

I'm writing an application in GTK. We have the need to support both VTE terminal API 2.90 and 2.91. So I created a silly compatibility layer between the two in a module called 'compatibility'. It looks like this.

```
import gi
try:
    gi.require_version('Vte', '2.91')
    vte_version = '2.91'
except ValueError:
    gi.require_version('Vte', '2.90')
    vte_version = '2.90'

from gi.repository import Vte


class CompatibleVteTerminal(Vte.Terminal):
    """A simple VTE terminal modified to be compatible with both 2.90
    and 2.91 API"""
    def __init__(self):
        Vte.Terminal.__init__(self)

    def spawn_sync(self, pty_flags, working_directory, argument_vector,
                   env_variables, glib_spawn_flags, child_setup,
                   child_setup_data, cancellable=None):
        """Returns the corresponden version os 'spawn_sync' method
        according to the Vte version the user has"""
        if vte_version == '2.91':
            return Vte.Terminal.spawn_sync(self, pty_flags, working_directory,
                                           argument_vector, env_variables,
                                           glib_spawn_flags, child_setup,
                                           child_setup_data, cancellable)
        elif vte_version == '2.90':
            return Vte.Terminal.fork_command_full(self, pty_flags,
                                                  working_directory,
                                                  argument_vector, env_variables,
                                                  glib_spawn_flags, child_setup,
                                                  child_setup_data, cancellable)
```

Now, I already had a terminal created in another module.

```
class Terminal(Vte.Terminal):
   """Do terminal stuff"""
```

Of course, I want this class to inherit now from my compatible terminal.

```
from compatibility import CompatibleVteTerminal as Vte.Terminal

class Terminal(Vte.Terminal):
    """Do terminal stuff"""
```

But this gives me a 'Invalid syntax' error. Apparently you can't import stuff with a dot in its name. How can I import my compatible terminal without modifying the original code?

Comment: You *could* import your CompatibleTerminal, dynamically create a `Vte` module, add your terminal to it, and that would work.  But if you're editing that file anyway to do this, why not just change Terminal to use an undotted superclass.

Comment: Any instructions or information on how to dynamically create a module and add an object to it? Seems... messy.

Comment: It would be somewhat messy, no doubt.  I'll throw together an example.

Comment: Why not emulate the gi module structure? That is, rather than just having a module called `compatibility` have a module called `compatibility.gi.repository.Vte`? And then import as `from compatibility.gi.repository import Vte`.

Comment: @Dunes that is a sensible idea, but it fails because the Vte module actually contains things outside of the terminal which I don't want to replicate. For example, Vte.Terminal.spawn_sync takes Vte.PtyFlags.DEFAULT as first argument. If I do this, it will look for Vte.PtyFlags in my compatibility layer, and of course it won't find it there.

Comment: @joaquinlpereyra I added an example of dynamically creating a module.  I still think there's likely a better way, but the dynamic module approach would allow you to not change the class's superclass specification.

Comment: Then you have bigger problems if you need two versions of the `Vte` module to be available simultaneously. You either need to make the `compatibility` module insert its classes into the appropriate `gi` modules (bad idea, could lead to weird bugs). Or directly import the class rather than the module. eg. `from compatibility import CompatibleVteTerminal as _Terminal` and `class Terminal(_Terminal): ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really think there is a better way, which was why I originally posted as a comment rather than an answer, but to illustrate how you might create a dynamic module and add a class to it, consider the following:

```
class AlternativeCounter:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        pass

    def __repr__(self):
        return "HA! I'm an imposter!"


use_stdlib_collections = False

if use_stdlib_collections:
    import collections
else:
    import imp
    collections = imp.new_module('collections')
    collections.Counter = AlternativeCounter


class MyCounter(collections.Counter):
    def foo(self):
        print("I'm a %r" % self.__class__.__name__)
        print("My parents are: %r" % self.__class__.__bases__)


c = MyCounter("12321")
c.foo()
print(c)
```

If `use_stdlib_collections = True`, this outputs:

```
I'm a 'MyCounter'
My parents are: <class 'collections.Counter'>
MyCounter({'2': 2, '1': 2, '3': 1})
```

If `use_stdlib_collections = False`, this outputs:

```
I'm a 'MyCounter'
My parents are: <class '__main__.AlternativeCounter'>
HA! I'm an imposter!
```

The order of the code may seem odd, in order to keep it all in one file I had to define AlternativeCounter above the conditional importing mechanic.  In practice, the code would probably look more like:

```
use_stdlib_collections = False

if use_stdlib_collections:
    import collections
else:
    import imp
    collections = imp.new_module('collections')
    from some_other_module import AlternativeCounter
    collections.Counter = AlternativeCounter

# ...
```

and `AlternativeCounter` would be placed in an external `some_other_module` module.

Depending on your usage, you might not even need to create an actual module, you could use an empty class:

```
# ...

class FakeModule: pass

if use_stdlib_collections:
    import collections
else:
    collections = FakeModule()
    collections.Counter = AlternativeCounter

#...
```

Note that in either case, however, any *additional* references to the `collections` module (e.g. `collections.OrderedDict`) (or in your case, additional references to the `Vte` module will fail without additional work.

---

#### Edit

Since you want to access additional attributes of the module (in your case `Vte`, in mine `collections`), you'll want a way of "falling back" on the real module in all cases except the ones you explicitly override.

Using the approach where you have a class masquerading as a module, you might be able to do something like the following:

```
class AlternativeCounter:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        pass

    def __repr__(self):
        return "HA! I'm an imposter!"

class ModuleWithFallback:
    def __init__(self, backup):
        self.backup = backup

    # Provide a fallback mechanism for un-overridden attribute access
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.backup, name)

    
use_stdlib_collections = False

if use_stdlib_collections:
    import collections
else:
    import collections as std_collections
    collections = ModuleWithFallback(std_collections)
    collections.Counter = AlternativeCounter


class MyCounter(collections.Counter):
    def foo(self):
        print("I'm a %r" % self.__class__.__name__)
        print("My parents are: %r" % self.__class__.__bases__)
 

c = MyCounter("12321")
c.foo()
print(c)

print("---")

# Despite defaultdict not being overridden, it still works as you would expect.
dd = collections.defaultdict(int)
dd["bar"] += 1
print(dd["bar"])    # 1
print(type(dd))     # <class 'collections.defaultdict'>
```

Here, `ModuleWithFallback` is a simple proxy-like class.  It's constructor takes a single argument, that of a module, which I imported under the alias `std_collections` so as not to conflict.  Now, when an attribute is accessed that isn't defined on the class (in the example above I use `collections.defaultdict`), it attempts to return the corresponding attribute of the "backup" module (in my case, the *real* collections module).

Note that this *still* may not work depending on the specifics of your classes, but with this code at least you have a fighting chance.

Comment: This is _really_ interesting. I will check it out. Unfortunately, I do need information from the original Vte module. I'm starting to think that, exactly because of that, my original request is indeed impossible. How would python know when to refer to the original Vte module and when to my compatibility class if they have same name? Seems undoable and unreasonable.

Comment: If you have additional references to the `Vte` module other than `Vte.Terminal` (which you want to "override") it's still not impossible.  The above code will definitely fail, but let me see if I can whip up something that would at least make a better attempt.

Comment: @joaquinlpereyra Updated the post to show how you might handle accessing other, non-overriden attributes of the module.